wxWidgets wxFlexGridSizer not "sizing" with the others
I'm not sure if this is a wxWidgets issue or a Code::Block issue, both or just me... but I have this screen that I rearranged because the buttons in the middle would get hidden by a panel that's adjacent to this so I just reworked it.
The problem is that the top SubModel name gridsizer expands, see beloow but the wxGrid/Node Ranges doesn't expand.
I've created the different grids to place the items in the hope that only the "table" would expand, but no matter what I try, only the top one does. Checked all settings between the two and they are all the same, with the exception of a diff type, StaticTest vs Grid.
Any ideas where I should look at next?  Thanks much -A
EDIT.... Arggg.. the image was deleted...
enter image description here

you should add some code and a screenshot of what it looks like and what you expect to see. Otherwise we can only guess what you mean...

you should also post the generated code for you GUI not the wxFB screenshot. Not too many people will understand what is happening. Also it would be nice if you could try and explain on the screenshot what you are looking for and how it should behave differently. Also see if the compiled code will behave like you want to - sometimes RAD tools are not very good with WYCIWYGs.
